# How to add text before column in tabular in LaTeX?

Tags: tables, spacing, columns

I want to add `\hfill` *before* a column in a `tabular` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{2cm}@{}l}
  \hfill First & Second\\
  \hfill Very long & Fourth
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The output I want and get is (with the first column flush-left):

```
    FirstSecond
Very longFourth
```

Now I would like to do the same but to add the `\hfill` in the header, like:

```
\begin{tabular}{@{\hfill}p{2cm}@{}l}
  First & Second\\
  Very long & Fourth
\end{tabular}
```

What I get is not the same:

```
First      Second
Very long  Fourth
```

I guess the `@{\hfill}` adds the `\hfill` after the zeroth column or some such thing, and not before the text of the first column.  Can this be fixed?

Comment: Please consider providing a full compilable MWE instead of a code snippet. You are probably looking for something like `>{\hfill}p{2cm}`, but why not just right-aligning the column?

Comment: don't use `p`  or `\hfill` use `wr{2m}`  (`array` package)

Comment: I will check out the `array` package.  Out of curiosity: no way to do this only with `tabular`?

Comment: A 2m wide column would be excessive even in the Saint Peter's Basilica, no matter how it is aligned. Try with 2cm  :)

Comment: @Fran Indeed, my CV is not this extensive.